# how to find best order and seasonal_order for sarimax model for different dataset (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, prediction

I am trying to predict future data based on given history data for different **dataset**.

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    dataset,
    order=(1,0, 0),
    seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 12),
    enforce_stationarity=False,
    enforce_invertibility=False
)
results = mod.fit()
```

But for configuration issue I am getting error. Then randomly generate order and seasonal order and checking it either error or not.

```
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]
np.random.shuffle(pdq)
np.random.shuffle(seasonal_pdq)
results, finished = False, False
for iii in pdq:
    for jjj in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
                dataset,
                order=iii,
                seasonal_order=jjj,
                enforce_stationarity=False,
                enforce_invertibility=False
            )
            results = mod.fit()
            dataset_pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=int(len(dataset)*0.8))
            # prediction = dataset_pred_uc.predicted_mean
            finished = True
        except Exception as error:
            continue
    if(finished):
        break
```

But I am getting different result for each time. Some time result is very good and some time it’s worse than I think.

How can I solve this type of problem, where dataset value is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the same result each time, the random numbers should be produced from the same seed each time. So set random.seed in your code (e.g., `np.random.seed(1234)`).